# Taking an e-mail address entered in a form and send to it in Django

Tags: django, forms, email, django-views

So I have part of a view:

```
nom = str(request.user.first_name) + " " + str(request.user.last_name)
sujet = 'Heures de benevolat/Volunteer hours'
a_qui = {'jacob.pkmn@gmail.com'}
de_qui = 'projetpersonnel.jacob@gmail.com'
message = get_template('formulaire_eleves/courriel.html').render(Context({'form': form, 'nom': nom}))

msg = EmailMessage(sujet, message, to=a_qui, from_email=de_qui)
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

Although another e-mail address is hardcoded right now, it is supposed to send an e-mail to the address a user entered into a form I have. How would I go about this? Also, everything works as planned right now, it's just I can't seem to figure out a way to get the e-mail address in the form and put it in "a_qui".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign request.POST.get(FORM_VARIABLE) to your local variables to capture POST data from users. In return you can craft reply by inserting your reply attributes into EmailMessage(). Here's how your code could look like:

```
nom = request.POST.get('first_name') + " " + request.POST.get('last_name')
sujet = request.POST.get('subject')
a_qui = request.POST.get('email')
de_qui = YOUR_REPLY_EMAIL
message = get_template('formulaire_eleves/courriel.html').render(Context({'form': form, 'nom': nom}))

msg = EmailMessage('REPLY_SUBJECT', message, a_qui, de_qui)
msg.send()
```

Comment: Answered my question, and then some! Thanks!